# Rewrite URL where one variable is changing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I am trying to get below .htaccess rewrite working where the `page=1` can have any numeric value

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^per_page\=10&page\=1&_embed&categories\=&categories_exclude\=31,32,92$
RewriteRule ^wp\-json/wp/v2/posts$ /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10&page=1&_embed&categories_exclude=31,32,92 [L]
```

So if the variable id `page=6` it stays that way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture the value of the `page` URL parameter in the `RewriteCond` regex (*CondPattern*) and use a corresponding `%<number>` backreference in the substitution string. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^per_page=10&page=(\d+)&_embed&categories=&categories_exclude=31,32,92$
RewriteRule ^wp-json/wp/v2/posts$ /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10&page=%1&_embed&categories_exclude=31,32,92 [L]
```

The regex `\d` is a shorthand character class for digits and is equivalent to the *long-hand* `[0-9]`.

The `%1` backreference contains the string captured by the first capturing subgroup, `(\d+)`, in the preceding *CondPattern* (ie. the value of the `page` URL parameter).

*Aside:* No need to backslash-escape `=` and `-` in the regex as they carry no special meaning in the context they are being used here.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

---

However, you might as well capture "everything" and save repetition, "simplifying" the *substitution string*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(per_page=10&page=\d+&_embed)&categories=(&categories_exclude=31,32,92)$
RewriteRule ^wp-json/wp/v2/posts$ /$0?%1%2 [L]
```

Here, we capture the part of the query string before and after the `&categories=` URL parameter (the section to be removed). These are saved in the `%1` and `%2` backreferences respectively.

The `$0` backreference contains the URL-path matched by the entire `RewriteRule` *pattern*.